# Using seekbar in android

Tags: java, android, media-player, seekbar

I am making an android application where i got a seekbar for some music. I got the seekbar to show the music playing status, where i currently am in the music playback. But how can i setup a listener so that i can say that the mediaplayer would play a specific place on a track? I know the code for setting the play time in mediaplayer, but how can i handle the click events from seekbar? like onClick() or anything similar?

FIXED:
My code:

```
package com.mycompany.appname;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;

public class MusicActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {
//Called when the activity is first created
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
EditText AddItemToListViewEditText;
  static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
      "Movies"
      };
  MediaPlayer mp1;
  String musicUri;
  Button PausePlay;
  int positionInt;
  SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer2;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.musicscreen);

    //Import views
    PausePlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PausePlay);
    slidingDrawer2 = (SlidingDrawer)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer2);

    //Setup onClickListener for the buttons
    PausePlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Setup mediaPlayer
    mp1 = new MediaPlayer();

    //Setup ListView
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, myList));

    //Setup seekBar
    final SeekBar progress = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.musicProgressBar);
    progress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/");
    myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(mFile.list()));
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, myList));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        //When an item is clicked, play it on a MediaPlayer
          //Play song
          positionInt = position;
          if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
              //Reset mediaPlayer
              mp1.reset();
              try {
                  musicUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/" + myList.get(positionInt);
                mp1.setDataSource(musicUri);
                mp1.prepare();
                mp1.start();
                slidingDrawer2.animateOpen();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          } else {
          try {
              musicUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/" + myList.get(position);
            mp1.setDataSource(musicUri);
            mp1.prepare();
            mp1.start();
            slidingDrawer2.animateOpen();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          //Setup seekBar
          final SeekBar progress = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.musicProgressBar);
          progress.setProgress(0);
          progress.setMax(mp1.getDuration());
          new CountDownTimer(mp1.getDuration(), 250) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (progress.getProgress() == mp1.getDuration()) {
                    mp1.reset();
                    progress.setProgress(0);
                } else {
                  progress.setProgress(mp1.getCurrentPosition());
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {}
          }.start();
        }
  }
    });
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser == true) {
        mp1.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
    } else {
        //Do nothing
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
            mp1.reset();
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
}

public void onClick(View src) {
    switch(src.getId()) {
    case R.id.PausePlay:
        if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
            mp1.pause();
            PausePlay.setText("Play");
        } else {
            mp1.start();
            PausePlay.setText("Pause");
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Musikk"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




    <ListView
        android:id="@+android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>


    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Spiller nå" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/musicProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >













                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/PausePlay"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pause" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should also check out the [Java variable naming conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). The last bullet on that page especially. Non-final variables (such as your PausePlay variable) should start with a lowercase letter. Camelcase starting with an uppercase letter should be reserved for classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to implement `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`, then implement the [onProgressChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html#onProgressChanged%28android.widget.SeekBar,%20int,%20boolean%29) method.

This is called when the progress is changed (eg a user click somewhere on the seekbar), and will provide you with the new position.

Example:

```
public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // Do something
}
```

Don't forget to register the OnSeekBarChanged listener with [seekBar.setOnseekBarChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html#setOnSeekBarChangeListener%28android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener%29)

Comment: Did you look at that link? It should have everything you need.
I updated my answer with an example method. There isn't much to it though, so I'm not sure what you expect to get out of me copying the method from the developer docs.

Comment: Shouldn't i override the method?

Comment: Yes, just like your OnClickListener. Start by changing your class declaration to `public class MusicActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnProgressChangedListener`, then stick the `onProgressChanged` method somewhere in your Activity.

Comment: I couldn't implement OnProgressChangedListener because i couldn't import it. It didn't say like import and neither the ctrl shift o worked. How can i do it, the OnSeekBarChangeListener is there though

Comment: The interface is `OnSeekBarChanged`. If you implement the OnSeekBarChanged interface, you must have the `onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)` method in your class. This is similar your click listener. If you implement OnClickListener, you must have the onClick method in your class.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you also need to register the seekBar's OnSeekBarChangeListener with [seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html#setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener))

Comment: should i use seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null); ? in that case, it doesn't work either. Srry for all the questions, i have never used a progressbar or seekbar in android before

Comment: No, you should use `seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this)`, because _this_ object (your Activity) is the one that implements the OnSeekBarChangeListener interface.
This is the seekBar equivalent of the line `PausePlay.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: I actually tried that but it came an error, i read the error and i placed in my onCreate() instead, and then it worked, but however, the sound now is terrible, like laggy and such of some weird reason, i'll investigate it a little bit

Comment: I found the solution! Since the seekBar was moving with the song, it was constantly being changed, seeking the mediaplayer all the time, therefor the quality was so bad. I added a little if statement checking wether the user og application triggered the seekBar movement, and made it seek only if the user touched, not if the application moved it. Take a look at my code now:-) Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (fromUser) {
                    mp1.seekTo(progress);
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                }

            }
```